Validation of complex mapping area calculation
I want to know whether the following  approach and computations are correct for calculating the area of image of a polynomial under a polynomial map. Here are my thoughts :
I want to to estimate the area $ A $ of the image of the unit disk under a polynomial map $z \mapsto p(z) $ thus I start with  using the formula derived from the complex derivative $p'(z) $ of the polynomial, given the mapping's holomorphic (complex-differentiable) nature everywhere in the complex plane.
By using the complex Jacobian determinant, the area formula  can be written as:
$$
A = \int_{|z| \leq 1} |p'(z)|^2 \, dA
$$
Here, $dA = r dr d\theta $ in polar coordinates, provided $ z = r e^{i\theta} $ so that we have :
$$
A =  \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 |p'(re^{i\theta})|^2 r \, dr \, d\theta
$$
where $p'(z) = a_1 + 2a_2 z + \cdots + na_n z^{n-1} .$ Thank you in advance for ny help and comments

Your approach is correct, and if you complete the computation, the answer is $A=\pi\sum n|a_n|^2$. And notice that the resulting area is "counted with multiplicity".

What if the area is not counted with multiplicity

That's a more difficult problem, for which there is no simple formula.
